# Java 17: MenuIterator is not abstract and does not override abstract method remove() in java.util.Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, default-method

I'm getting the following error while implementing the java.util.Iterator interface in my class:

**java: MenuIterator is not abstract and does not override abstract method remove() in java.util.Iterator.**

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MenuIterator implements Iterator<MenuItem> {
    private final MenuItem[] items;
    private int position = 0;

    public MenuIterator(MenuItem[] menuItems) {
        this.items = menuItems;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return position < items.length && items[position] != null;
    }

    public MenuItem next() {
        return items[position++];
    }
}
```

remove() method is a default method in the Iterator interface, as well as forEachRemaing() method.

```
    default void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
    }

    default void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        while (hasNext())
            action.accept(next());
    }
```

However, I am not forced to implement forEachRemaing(), but I do have to implement remove(). Also, the code works without implementing remove() if I run it from Eclipse, but gives an error in IntelliJ IDEA.

Does anyone know why I would need to provide an implementation for the default remove() method? Why should I provide it for one method and not for another? And why does it work without implementation in one IDE and not in another?

Comment: What version of javac are you compiling it with? btw, always use `@Override` when overriding methods

Comment: Version 17.0.7. Eclipse removed annotations actually because it's rather an implementation than 'overriding', but I agree, it's more obvious if the @Override annotation is there

Comment: I know what you're saying. Yes it *is* an implementation but the annotation will show errors and won't let you believe you've overridden a method when you haven't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `remove()` method in `java.util.Iterator` has a `default` implementation *now*, but it didn't in older versions. Specifically, it gained this in java8 (because java8 introduced `default` methods - but Iterator's `remove` is older than that).

You have configured your intellij that your source code is versioned at 7 or lower, and/or have told intellij to compile and run it all on a JDK at version 7 or below.

These versions are very very obsolete/unmaintained/outdated; the lowest java version still in common use is java 8; there is very little reason to write libraries such that they run on even that very very low version.

If you truly want to support that version, you *have to* write `remove()` by hand - that same version (java7 or below) *did not have* a `forEachRemaining` method at all, hence why you get no errors about it not being in your implementation: Either it wasn't there at all, *or* it has a default impl. Unlike `remove()`, which pre-8 was there and had no `default` (because the feature didn't exist), and post-8 was still there but now with a `default`.

Exactly how you've set up your project so that you ended up with something configured at 7 or below is not clear from your question. If you have issues fixing it, you should find a tutorial or ask a separate question from this one.

Comment: Yes, the target bytecode version was set to 7, it was a default IntelliJ setting. It compiles after I set it to 8. I started learning Java from version 8 :) thanks!